# How to run Maven Javadoc in a project with pom packaging?

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a project that packages the delivery of a software using the assembly plugin. The packaging of the project is pom.

To make a nicer documentation i am using the dependency plugin to download the sources of the different projects and then using the javadoc plugin to generate a new documentation that merges the javadoc for the different projects into one.

The issue I am having is that maven javadoc will not run if the packaging is pom. 
It complains with the message: Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package

However, if I put packaging jar it works. Unfortunately then an empty unwanted jar file is generated.

Is there a way to get the maven javadoc to run with packaging pom?

Cheers,
Javi

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I have found was to set the packaging in the pom to jar and prevent maven jar plugin to generate the jar.